# How to find two n-tuple matrices are equal?

Tags: python, matrix, tuples, equality

I tried this program

```
from pprint import pprint

m = int(input("Number of matrices: "))
rows = int(input("Enter the Number of rows : "))
columns = int(input("Enter the Number of Columns: "))

matrices = []
for i in range(m):
    print("Enter the elements of Matrix:")
    matrix_i = [[tuple(map(float, input().split(" "))) for c in range(columns)]
                for r in range(rows)]
    print("Matrix no: ", i + 1)
    for n in matrix_i:
        print(n)
    print()
    matrices.append(matrix_i)
pprint(matrices)

def areequal(A,B):   
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns):
            if (((A[i][j][0] ==  B[i][j][0]), (A[i][j][1] ==  B[i][j][1]), (A[i][j][2] ==  B[i][j][2]))):
                return 1
    return 0
for m1 in matrices:
    for m2 in matrices:
        if (areequal(m1, m2)==1):
            print(m1, m2)
            print("Matrices are identical")
        else:
            print(m1, m2)
            print("Matrices are not identical")
```

got the output for the below matrices to be identical

```
m1=
[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) (8.0, 7.0, 6.0)]
[(8.0, 7.0, 6.0) (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)]
m2 =
[(3.0, 4.0, 5.0) (9.0, 8.0, 7.0)]
[(3.0, 4.0, 5.0) (9.0, 8.0, 7.0)]
m3 =
[(0.0, 9.0, 7.0) (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)]
[(8.0, 7.0, 6.0) (8.0, 7.0, 6.0)]
```

For example, like this

```
[[(0.0, 9.0, 7.0), (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)], [(8.0, 7.0, 6.0), (8.0, 7.0, 6.0)]] [[(3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (9.0, 8.0, 7.0)], [(3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (9.0, 8.0, 7.0)]]
Matrices are identical

[[(0.0, 9.0, 7.0), (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)], [(8.0, 7.0, 6.0), (8.0, 7.0, 6.0)]] [[(0.0, 9.0, 7.0), (2.0, 3.0, 4.0)], [(8.0, 7.0, 6.0), (8.0, 7.0, 6.0)]]
Matrices are identical
```

Even though the matrices are not same/equal got the output to be identical.

why am I getting all the matrices to be identical? How to find two n-tuple matrices are equal? How to find the given matrices are equal pairwise (like (m1 & m2), (m2 & m3), (m3 & m1))? How to get the result without repetition(like (m1 & m1), (m2 & m2), (m3 & m3))?

Comment: Side remark: instead of working with `input` which could be quit annoying when _testing_ the program you could use `random` package and fix the `seed` so you can reproduce the same output. If it works properly then switch to `input`

Comment: Whats the reason for avoiding the normal `m1 == m2` check?

Answer (score 2):

Commas create tuples, not Boolean values. Tuples are truthy. The line

```
if (((A[i][j][0] ==  B[i][j][0]), (A[i][j][1] ==  B[i][j][1]), (A[i][j][2] ==  B[i][j][2]))):
```

Is essentially

```
if True:
```

Instead, use

```
if (((A[i][j][0] ==  B[i][j][0]) and (A[i][j][1] ==  B[i][j][1]) and (A[i][j][2] ==  B[i][j][2]))):
```